# How to increase the autocomplete search results in webform

Tags: webform-civicrm

How to change the module code to increase the autocomplete search results in webform. we have two contact one is enquirer and another is organisation its result 12 on autocomplete.

Comment: I don't understand your comments about 'enquirer and organisation'

Comment: i am Searching existing contact in the civicrm webform. autocomplete result limited to 12. how to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like line 669 here:
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform_civicrm/blob/7.x-4.x/includes/contact_component.inc#L669

You can try changing the 12 to something else. It might work to replace it with `Civi::settings()->get('search_autocomplete_count')` and then it should use the value under Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Search Preferences -> Autocomplete Results. I haven't tested that.

Comment: Thanks demerit. I have changed search Preferences -> Autocomplete Results to 20 but it does not reflects. can you please share path of drupal component file to change.

Comment: Line 669 in sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/contact_component.inc

Comment: Thanks for your advice.. It is working now.

Comment: Great!.........